# Dimensional Analysis of tunnelling current expression

Tags: dimensional-analysis, quantum-tunneling

I have been racking my head trying to get the units to work on an expression for 1D tunnel current through a potential barrier.  This expression is straight from S. Sze's "Physics of Semiconductor Devices", its eqn. 114 of chapter 1 in the 3rd edition.  It gives a current density through a barrier as a function of fermi occupancy and DOS of states left and right of the barrier, as well as the tunnelling probability.

$$ J_t = \frac{qm^*}{2\pi^2\hbar^3}\int{T_tF_AN_A(1-F_B)N_B dE} $$

Does this seem correct from a dimension analysis POV?  I should be getting Amps but do not!  Using standard MKS units, $ F_i$'s having inverse Energy*Volume.  Any thoughts as to whether this expression is wonky, or just me? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect to get amps per square cm for a 1D case? There is no area...

Comment: Yes, my mistake, in 1D only Amps, however still not what I seem to get.

Comment: Can you show your working - what is the value (dimensionality) you get? How can $F_i$ be inverse Energy * Volume when volume has no meaning.

Comment: Sure, volume is dimension dependent "volume", although the book clearly defines units for all symbols in the appendix.
They have they following defined units:
$ q = C, m^* = Kg, \hbar = Js, N_{i} = \frac{1}{eV*m^3} $
Apart from the difference in eV/J which will just be numeric factor, I still get end result of  which seems ridiculous

Comment: $ \frac{C*s^5}{kg^3m^{14}} $

Comment: Given the term $(1-F_b)$ appears, $F_b$ must be unitless.

Comment: Yes, The T and F terms are unitless, as they are tunnelling probabilities and occupancy factors.  The integral is just summing the product of tunnelling probability,occupancy of states before and after the barrier, and DOS